# Question About Proof of the Open Mapping Theorem

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, proof-explanation, open-map

Below is a proof of the Open Mapping Theorem:

[image: Source: Complex Analysis, Stein et al.]

I understand the proof, except I am unsure how we can guarantee that there exists a $\delta >0$ such that $f(z)\neq w_0$ for all $\delta = \mid(z-z_0)\mid$.

Here's my reasoning why this might be the case:

Suppose there was no such $\delta >0$.  Then in particular there is a point $z_n$ on each circle $\frac{1}{n}= \mid(z-z_0)\mid$ for $n=N,N+1,...$ such that $f(z_n)=w_0$ (for some sufficiently large integer N).  This is a bounded sequence in the closed disk $\frac{1}{N}=\mid(z-z_0)\mid$.  Hence it has a convergent subsequence.  f is constant on this subsequence and hence f must be constant everywhere in the disk because f is holomorphic.

Is this reasoning correct?  Am I making it too complicated.  Is there simpler explanation.

Comment: Yes, you are making it complicated. If $\mid z-z_n \mid =1/n$ then $z_n$ converges to $z_0$ so there is no need to extract a convergent subsequence.

Comment: "Below is a proof of the Open Mapping Theorem:" Where?